# ORA-01843: not a valid month JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, ora-01843

I am using JPA 1 and have a native query executing the following statement:

```
select NVL (max (x.some), 0) from (select count (1) as some, service from some_table Where trunc    (fh_report) = '09 / 01/2015 'group by service) x
```

marking the error is:

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

However, if I copy the sentence in ORACLE ide this runs perfectly, I have two databases, one for testing and one for production, production marks this mistake and in testing dont.

I want to know also, what is better?? include the dates into string and then pass it to jpa like this?

```
String sql = "select NVL (max (x.some), 0) from (select count (1) as some, service from some_table Where trunc    (fh_report) = '09 / 01/2015 'group by service) x ";

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
```

or pass the date value as parameter?

This could be the reason from error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post the actual executed SQL statement, or is that actually being executed as-is? The date format looks odd.

Comment: Hi Chylis yes the sentence its executed like i posted, if i run it in sql developer or any another sql ide, it runs perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Implicit date conversion may depend on both your client and your server settings.  The same code will often run in one environment but not another.

One solution is to use an ANSI date literal, in the ISO 8601 format:

```
trunc(fh_report) = date '2015-09-01'
```

I'm guessing the original code uses the American date format.  The advantage of ISO 8601 is that no person or computer needs to guess, it is unambiguous.

Comment: Hello Jon thanks 4 answer, the strange thing is that if the problem was the configuration of NLS_DATE_FORMAT in database, the query would not work in sql navigator or any other ide sql, I am using weblogic as application server, if I set my datasource to point to my database production data, make that mistake, however, if pointed to my test database error no-show, NLS_DATE_FORMAT is configured as follows for both bases: NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD / MM / RR. Some idea?, btw, how I put it in the literal as I RECOMMEND?

Comment: There are many ways to set NLS_DATE_FORMAT so you want to avoid depending on it.  It could use the server default or may be set by a driver, an IDE, a custom script called by an IDE, a logon trigger, an object executed in the session, etc.  I understand the urge to blame the problem on environment differences but this is really a code issue.  This is an environment difference all code should expect.  To use the literal, simply replace `'09 / 01/2015 '` with `date '2015-09-01'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
trunc    (fh_report) = '09 / 01/2015 '
```

If you're going to TRUNC() a date, the resulting value should be "DD-MON-YYYY" as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm).

I imagine if you changed your = text to

```
trunc    (fh_report) = '01-SEP-15'
```

it should work.

However, I am confused that you said it works in your IDE.  I can't imagine it working unless you have different databases or versions.

Comment: That documentation is only an example of a possible date format.  The real date format will depend on the client and server settings.

Comment: That's the format I've always seen with the Oracle DBs I've worked with.  Perhaps it's the default.  @JonHeller, is there any way to set or view that setting?